# smtp connect() failed in PHP using phpmailer Library

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

I have Found Error to send mail in PHP using phpmailer Library.any one can answer this Error.
Thank you.

smtp connect() failed. https://github.com/phpmailer/phpmailer/wiki/troubleshooting

```
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/class.smtp.php';

    $rtn = false;
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port       = 587;
    $mail->Username   = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->SetFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'Smart Saver Support');
    $mail->AddReplyTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'Smart Saver Support');
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($msg);

    $rtn = $mail->Send();
    return $rtn;
```

Comment: Did you go through the troubleshooting steps the error message is pointing you to? What are the results? Please add that to your question.

Comment: Try with set port `465` instead of `587`

Comment: Yes  Mailer Error:  $mail->ErrorInfo;'

Comment: I was try Both Port 465 and 587 but cant work it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey Do you `Allow less secure apps to access your Gmail account` ?
if you not allow less secure apps enable and Run again and see the result.

Here is the Example:
https://devanswers.co/allow-less-secure-apps-access-gmail-account/

Comment: Yes @jayesh You also  are Right. a was not Allow less secure apps in gmail
 thank you. for answering

Answer (score 2):

It's maybe because of the wrong username and password given in SMTP authentication or 
SMTP port blocked in mail server firewalls.

If you are using Gmail account, please check this link and turn off the "Allow less secure apps".

Here is the URL:
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Then try to send email again.

Comment: Yes You are Right. a was not `Allow less secure apps`

Comment: Yes i was say same step as sachin answers